Can you set permission classes per function in class-based views?
Let's say we have the following class-based view (CBV) implementing DRF's APIView:
class ExampleListAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request):
        '''
        List all examples
        '''
        examples = Example.objects.all()
        serializer = ExampleListSerializer(examples, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        '''
        Create new example
        '''
        serializer = ExampleListSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Using permission_classes to set authentication policy in CBV, the policy is applied to all methods of class. Is it possible to set permission per function in a CBV, e.g.
class ExampleListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request): # Apply [AllowAny]
        # logic

    def post(self, request): # Apply [IsAuthenticated]
        # logic

Or you have to use function-based views to achieve this behavior?

You could make something that only checks a permission for a certain method:
class ForMethod(BasePermission):
    def __init__(self, permission, *methods):
        self.permission = permission
        self.methods = set(map(str.casefold, methods))

    def __call__(self):
        return self

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method.casefold() in self.methods:
            self.permission().has_permission(request, view)
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method.casefold() in self.methods:
            self.permission().has_object_permission(request, view, obj)
        return True
and work with:
class ExampleListAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [
        ForMethod(AllowAny, 'get'),
        ForMethod(IsAuthenticated, 'post'),
    ]

    def get(self, request):  # Apply [AllowAny]
        # logic
        pass

    def post(self, request):  # Apply [IsAuthenticated]
        # logic
        pass
You can even work with this as an algebra of permissions:
PostAuthenticated = ForMethod(AllowAny, 'get') & ForMethod(
    IsAuthenticated, 'post'
)


class ExampleListAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [PostAuthenticated]
    # …

Thanks for the detailed answer! I experimented a bit with custom permissions and I got it. However, the code you provided doesn't work as expected. In fact, it works like giving "AllowAny" permission to all requests. Can you figure out if it's something wrong with it, maybe the return values in has_permission() and has_object_permission(), so I can accept the answer?

Ok, one thing needs to be changed are the returns in has_permission() and has_object_permission(). It should be return self.permission().has_permission(request, view) and return self.permission().has_object_permission(request, view, obj), instead of return True. Otherwise, the function allows everytime.

The other thing that doesn't work as expected is the bitwise operand. It raises TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'ForMethod' and 'ForMethod'. So, using the two ForMethod in permission classes, if the first is rejected, authorization is forbidden.

Please, fix the minor mistakes to accept the answer! :) Maybe provide a solution for combining custom permissions with algebra?

Based on willeM_ Van Onsem's answer, I'm posting a workaround that overcomes the issue with combining custom permissions (see my comment).
class MyPermission(BasePermission):
    def __init__(self, permissions_dict):
        self.permissions_dict = {k.casefold():v for k, v in permissions_dict.items()}

    def __call__(self):
        return self

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method.casefold() in self.permissions_dict.keys():
            return self.permissions_dict[request.method.casefold()]().has_permission(request, view)
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method.casefold() in self.permissions_dict.keys():
            return self.permissions_dict[request.method.casefold()]().has_object_permission(request, view, obj)
        return False

class ExampleAPIView(APIView):
    permissions_dict = {'GET': AllowAny,
                       'POST': IsAuthenticated}
    permission_classes = [
        MyPermission(permissions_dict)
    ]

    # code

It's very similar to aforementioned answer, except for using a dictionary to define permissions as:
# {<request.method>: <built-in permission>}

